# Hibernate - get ScrollableResults from DAO in Service Layer

Tags: java, hibernate

In some cases I need to read all rows of a database table for batch processing. For communication with db I use DAOs. So on service layer I could do something like `dao.getAll()`. For that I need to return each row of db from dao. In case of “out of memory error” I can’t return a `List` containing all entities, because the table is very big. Pagination wouldn’t be a good solution, because it causes multiple database calls. 
So there is a thing called `ScrollableResults` which allows me to scroll through all entities and process each row without flooding the memory. Since I am using a DAO I must return each row from DAO to service layer. How can I achieve this? Are there other solutions to solve this problem? I am using Hibernate with an embedded Derby Database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Query interface and Criteria as well..

```
Query query = session.createQuery(query);
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
// iterate over results
while (results.next()) {
    Object row = results.get();
    // process row then release reference
    // you may need to evict() as well
}
results.close();
```

here Hibernate will still cache results in the Session, so you’ll need to call session.evict() or session.clear() every so often.

when caching is not required, it may be better to use StatelessSession.

```
ScrollableResults results = session.createQuery(query) .setReadOnly(true).setFetchSize( 1000 ).setCacheable(false).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY)
```

Comment: Okay, but doing it that way I would have business logic in my DAO while processing the results. That´s what I wanted to avoid. I thought I could get the results outside the DAO and process them in another class. Is that possible?